# replace the . character and put \" around the strings on each side if the . is not surrounded by numbers

Tags: java

I have a string like:

`"This is my abc.def ght.123 example 12.34 test"`

I'd like to change to:

`"This is my \"abc def\" \"ght 123\" example 12.34 test"`

How to do using regular expression in java?
Thanks
Isa

Comment: Are there only sequences with one dot or might something like `abc.def.ghi.jkl` be present as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are only one-dot sequences like `abc.def` or `ght.123` try the following:

```
String input = "This is my abc.def ght.123 example 12.34 test";

input = input.replaceAll("\\b([a-zA-Z]+)\\.([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\\b", "\\\"$1 $2\\\"");

System.out.println( input );
//output: This is my "abc def" "ght 123" example 12.34 test
```

The expression used is means: any sequence of characters followed by a dot and a sequence of characters or digits (the `\b` is a word boundary to prevent matches of (`_abc.def`, if you want them as well you could add the underscore to the character class or remove the `\b`).

The replacement would then replace the match with `\"$1 $2\"` where `$1` is the content of the first group `([a-zA-Z]+)` and `$2` is the content of the second group `([a-zA-Z0-9]+)`.

*Update*:

For the required input `"This is my complexe string 12.34 ab.cd a+-.12 34.0+b zer.123.456 or 12.34.56 etc"` (see the comment), the following expression might be used:

```
(?i)(?<=^|\s)([a-z\+\-]+)\.([a-z0-9\+\-]+)(?=\s|$)
```

Here `(?i)` means the expression should be case insensitive, `(?<=^|\s)` means match either if we're at the start of the string or after a whitespace, `(?=\s|$)` means match if a whitespace or the end of the string follows.

The core expression is still `([a-z\+\-]+)\.([a-z0-9\+\-]+)`. As you can see, I only added `+` and `-` to the character classes (note that it would be possible to write `-` instead of `\-` but then the meaning of the minus character would depend on its position in the character class). If you want to support more characters, add them to the character classes as needed. For more information on predefined character classes like `\d` or `p{L}` see [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html) and [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html).

Comment: Thanks for your reply
With your suggested expression, the group [a-zA-Z0-9]+ works for only the normal character and digit. But for the special characters, it will not work. (for example, the string like "This is my special group a-+b.cdf used for test" )

Comment: @Isabelle well, you are free to add characters to the character class as you like. It's hard to guess what should match and what shouldn't without and thorough definition and more examples.

Comment: I mean, if the . character is not surrounded by a numbers (left sided and right side), we will replace it by space and put \" around the strings

Comment: @Isabelle, in that case you might need a slightly different expression to get all points not surrounded by numbers. Again the request for examples (otherwise its really hard to help): should ` .123`, `a12.45`, `1.2.3`, `a.1.2.3` etc. match?

Comment: I will give you an example like this:
"This is my complexe string 12.34 ab.cd a+-.12 34.0+b zer.123.456 or 12.34.56 etc"
I'd like to have the output like:
"This is my complexe string 12.34 \"ab cd\" \"a+- 12\" zer.123.456 or 12.34.56 etc"
Hope my example is clair this time.
Thanks

Comment: @Isabelle, where did that `34.0+b` go?

Comment: I'm sorry for my mistake. The string after changing is: "This is my complexe string 12.34 \"ab cd\" \"a+- 12\" \"34 0+b\" zer.123.456 or 12.34.56 etc"